# How can I read coordinate values from the plot graph？

Tags: r

I have drawn a plot graph [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXMqm.jpg)

I want to read the coordinate values of the intersection dot in the following graph.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S0LT.png)
Are there any packages or functions to do this?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes,  Please look at the functions `locator` and `identify`  depending on whether you only want to get the coordinates of plotted ploibts or arbitrary points on your graph.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved it.